# I need to write console application which runs once in every month

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, console-application

Hi I have MVC C# project. In that i need to implement billing function which runs once in every month and charge customers. When I did some research on this i got to know that for scheduler functionality, console application is the easiest approach and one can configure in windows when that console application should run. 
But My doubt is since this is part of my project do I need to create console application by going to :

```
File -> New -> Project from existing code ??
```

I am using database first approach so after creating console application can I access my database in a same way I used to do it in MVC?

Comment: [`Task Scheduler`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler)?

Comment: You'll want to extract common functionality between both applications into a class library which both can use.  Then all three of those projects would be in the same solution and the two application projects (the console app and the web app) would reference the class library project.

Comment: @SonerGönül Yes task scheduler is where we schedule when to run tasks.But my doubt is can i create console application inside my project and can i access my tables like i do in MVC by using database first approach??

Comment: @all can someone tell me why i got -1 for this question. I am new to this so let me know what mistake i did in this question so i can improve next time!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But my doubt is can i create console application inside my project

Not inside the project, create separate console application inside your existing solution.

```
File -> New -> Project -> C# (Language) -> Console Application
```

If you have your Database related code in a separate project, then add the reference to that project in your Console Application, and then you will be able to use the methods/classes.

If you don't have database code in separate project then you can add reference to your existing MVC project, but it would be better if you can extract out the Data Layer in a separate [Class library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d11h6832%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and then reference it.

Once the application is completed you can use [Task Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) to schedule your application to run once a month

Comment: Great.this is what i needed. I have one doubt now.You told if you have database related code in a separate project then add reference.I am using MVC database fist approach and i have database code written automatically since i used this approach.Can i refer to this??

Comment: @Raj, move your Database first code, or the model generation to a separate class library, that way you would be able to access it in MVC as well as Console app

Comment: Hi if you don't mind can you tell me how can i move my database first code to class library and access it? I never did this before. Its okay if you can give me some links also where they have explained this procedure.

Comment: @Raj, simplest way would be to create a Class Library type project, and copy your database code/files from MVC project to there, After that remove the code/files from your MVC project. Reference the class library in your MVC project and build. See if you get errors. Try resolving errors one by one and make sure you are not referencing any Database code from MVC project directly. Once that is done then you can use that class library in other projects as well. There is no built in function for something like that in Visual studio to my knowledge. You have to do it manually.